# Queue interface in Java and default interface

Tags: java

I am reading about default interfaces in Java. I am say trying to implement a Queue interface but do not wish to write implementation of all the methods. I wonder how do I do that because the "Queue" and "Collections" interface do not have default methods in Java

Comment: I think you are looking for [abstract classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

Comment: How about implementing [`AbstractQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractQueue.html)? You only need to implement 5 methods.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to extend an already implemented subclass and override methods of our choice.

For example, we can extend [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) and override peek() if we want to

```
class MyQueue<E> extends ArrayDeque<E> {
    @Override
    public E peek() {
        return null;
    }
}
```